# Delphi Prism / VS 2008: Switching from code to design with one key?

Tags: delphi, visual-studio-2008, ide, oxygene

I've used several Versions of the Delphi IDE for many years. When I'm using Delphi Prism, I have to deal with Visual Studio - in my case especially VS 2008.

One of the most annoying things to me is that I have to right-click on my form to switch to the code editor and vice versa. In Delphi, one could simply press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to switch between code and form designer.

Is there a way to let this shortcut work in Visual Studio? It seems to me that I at least need 2 shortcuts when I take a look at the Keyboard options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the free [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/).  This is a series of IDE enhancements designed to make you more productive and includes a Delphi keyboard mapping for Visual Studio.

Best regards,

Simon

Answer (score 5):

You can use default keys:

- From "Form Designer" -  <kbd>F7</kbd>
- From Code To "Form Designer" - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: And you can easily define any key in VS. However, I don't think there is a "CodeDesignerToggle" command in VS, just "ToCode" and "ToDesigner" so it would have to stay two keys, like F12 and Shift+F12 if you like F12 better.

Answer (score 2):

I've simulated Delphi's behavior for just the <kbd>F12</kbd> key by using the keyboard options to bind <kbd>F12</kbd> to `View.ViewCode`, `View.ViewMarku`p, and `View.ViewDesigner`.

You can bind them in different views depending on how you want to rotate between them. For example, in ASP.NET applications I use the following:

- HTML Editor Source View <kbd>F12</kbd> ==> `View.ViewCode`
- Text Editor <kbd>F12</kbd> ==> `View.ViewDesigner`
- HTML Editor Design View <kbd>F12</kbd> ==> `View.ViewMarkup`